# Boot: Started Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown

Tags: boot, boot-issues

I have been using Raspi as a local Django server for a few months now. One day, when I came back from work the local server was not working anymore so I decided to unplug and plug back the power.

Since then, I have not been able to complete the boot of the Raspi. It hangs at:

> Boot: Started Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown

see photo below 
[image]

Find herebelow my config file:

```
# For more options and information see
# http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
# and your display can output without overscan
#disable_overscan=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
#hdmi_group=1
#hdmi_mode=1

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
dtparam=spi=on
enable_uart=1
# Uncomment this to enable the lirc-rpi module
#dtoverlay=lirc-rpi

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on
dtoverlay=tft35a
#dtoverlay=ads7846,cs=1,penirq=17,penirq_pull=2,speed=1000000,keep_vref_on=1,swapxy=1,pmax=255,xohms=60,xmin=200,xmax=3900,ymin=200,ymax=3900

#display_rotate=2
startx=0
```

I added the `startx=0` to see if there was any difference but no.

Here is how my `cmdline` looks:

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 console=ttyAMA0,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait fbcon=map:10 fbcon=font:ProFont6x11 logo.nologo
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Remove `quiet` from `/boot/cmdline.txt` and try again. Please don't post logs as screenshots, especially if the error message isn't in them. Consider how long it will take you to start from scratch (or from a backup), maybe losing several hours debugging the system isn't worth it.

Comment: Thanks @DmitryGrigoryev! There is no `quiet` on my `cmdline.txt`. Alright, no future images. Any other ideas?

Comment: Check the root FS with `fsck` on a working system to be sure it's clean. Next, set up persistent kernel log by setting`Storage=persistent` in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` and browse through logs in `/var/log/journal` after a reboot. Assuming you have access to the roof FS of course.

Comment: Ditto that you have to run `fsck` on the root filesystem before you can debug this further.